# What does $f(a_1, \ldots , a_n)$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

This is probably very elementary, however, I'm not sure what it exactly means. I just started reading the book *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*, and the notion of $f(a_1, \ldots , a_n)$ comes up right after the definition of an affine space. The author says, before every first bringing $f(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$,

> "Let us see how polynomials relate to affine space. The key idea is that a polynomial $f= \sum \limits_{\alpha} a_{\alpha} x^{\alpha} \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ gives a function $$f \colon k^n \to k$$ defined as follows: given $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in k^n$, replace every $x_i$ by $a_i$ in the expression for for $f$. Since all of the coefficients also lie in $k$, this operation gives an element $f(a_1 , \ldots , a_n) \in k$."

Any further explanation as to what $f(a_1 , \ldots , a_n)$ is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hmm, is there something in that definition that's confusing? It seems pretty clear to me.  It's just the usual function evaluation. e.g. if $f(x,y) = x + y$ then $f(2,3) = 5$.

Comment: Well, it's confusing, because the authors appear to be using $a_i$ to mean two different things.  Keep in mind that $\alpha $ is a vector, not an  integer. Thus if $\alpha =(1,1,1,\cdots, 1)\in k^n$ we have $x^{\alpha}$ is the monomial $x_1x_2\cdots x_n$.  Does it make more sense now?

Comment: It is the evaluation of the polynomial $f$ in $n$ indeterminates at the point $(a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n)\in k^n$.

Comment: @Bernard  I think it's confusing that $a_*$ simultaneously denotes a coefficient of the polynomial $f$ and one of it's arguments.  Of course, for the coefficients we don't have single entry subscripts, but the notation looks the same.

Comment: Thank you all for clearing this up. I understand now.

Comment: But as a coefficient, it is not $a_i$, but $a_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a multi-index/exponent.

Comment: @Bernard  Oh, agreed.  But I expect that's the source of the confusion.  They both look like $a_*$ after all.  Or maybe I'm wrong, and that's not what confused the OP...but when I first read it, it took me a moment to realize that $a_*$ changed its meaning depending on the context.

Comment: I know this book, and I agree it's better not to skim through it. Some decades ago, there was a less confusional notation for these multi-index/exponents: underlining it (like $a_{\underline{\alpha}}\mathbf x^{\underline{\alpha}}$).

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the overloading of $a$.  That could potentially be confusing.